# How can I set a property on a Converter object at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a list of dates and values (temperatures). I have a valueconverter object that colors the background of each row if the temperature is too high or too low. This code works fine:

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="GraphTableDataRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource DatagridAlarmConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

C#: converter

```
public class DatagridAlarmConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double? HiAlarm = null;
    public double? LoAlarm = 20;
    public Brush HiAlarmColor = Brushes.Red;
    public Brush LoAlarmColor = Brushes.Blue;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double? input = value as double?;

        if (input != null)
        {
            if (HiAlarm != null)
            {
                if (input > HiAlarm)
                {
                    return HiAlarmColor;
                }
            }
            if (LoAlarm != null)
            {
                if (input < LoAlarm)
                {
                    return LoAlarmColor;
                }
            }
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

C#: Datagrid creation

```
...
DataGrid dGrid = new DataGrid();
dGrid.Style = FindResource("GraphTableDataGridStyle") as Style;
dGrid.RowStyle = FindResource("GraphTableDataRowStyle") as Style;
dGrid.ItemsSource = dsf.BoundedData;
...
```

It correctly changes the background color of every row where the temperature is less than 20.

Now I want to change the HiAlarm and LoAlarm values dynamically at run time. If I could create a style in code behind with a binding to the converter, I would do it something like this:

```
DatagridAlarmConverter dac = new DatagridAlarmConverter();
dac.HiAlarm = HighAlarm; //public property in code behind object
dac.LoAlarm = LowAlarm;
//use this object somehow in style
```

But I don't know how to attach this converter object to a style in code behind.

Alternatively, I thought of passing the Code Behind object to the converter as a property since the class contains the HighAlarm and LowAlarm properties I need:

```
<Style x:Key="GraphTableDataRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource DatagridAlarmConverter}, ConverterProperty=this}"/>
</Style>
```

I could then change the converter code to check the properties of the object to extract the HighAlarm and LowAlarm values.

But there is no "this" reference in XAML so I don't know how to do that either.

So my question is, how can I add a converter to a style in code behind OR how can I pass the parent object to a converter at in XAML.

Comment: you can sort of do a "this' call. But i have only used it for a binding path. not sure if it would work on other fields. Use a equals then a period : "=.". I use it like `Binding Path=.`

Comment: The converter's a resource, right? Can't you get the instance by key with `FindResource()` just as you did with the other resources?

Comment: To your actual question. have you explored doing a multibinding with a multivalueconverter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed Plunkett put me on the trail of a solution. I googled how to add a dynamic resource and stumbled across some code that did what I needed.

I determined that I could create a binding to a converter in a style in code behind like this:

```
DatagridAlarmConverter dac = new DatagridAlarmConverter();
dac.HiAlarm = HighAlarm;
dac.LoAlarm = LowAlarm;
Style rowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Converter = dac, 
            Path = new PropertyPath("Value")
        }));
```

I then used this new rowstyle instead of the XAML one.